# printing a message in mips

Tags: assembly, printf, mips

I have the following code in my program

```
li $v1, 4              #system call code for Print String
la $a0, LC             #load address of message into $a0
syscall                #print the string
li $v1, 1              #system call code for Print Integer
move $a0, $v0          #move value to be printed to $a0
syscall                #print result
```

and

```
.rdata
LC: .asciiz "The factorial of 10 is : "
```

but when I try to use it in mips it says:

Unknown system call: 3628800

where 3628800 is the result I want to print!

What is going wrong?Can I use jal printf instead and how should I write it?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system call number goes into `$v0`, not `$v1`.

Comment: thanks,I'm new to assembly and mips so I didn't know there is a specific register we have to use. Any idea about using printf???